# Network Visualisation within R

Tags: r, network-programming, visualization

So I'm following this tutorial: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335679918_Network_visualization_with_R

Using the mock data they have provided there is something I'm struggling to understand. On page 59, **'es'** is created, however when it is printed the heads and tails are incorrect? They do not match the id’s specified in the csv? However when labels are added to the plot created they are correct?

I am misunderstanding something? Are the heads and tails specified in the edge list not meant to match the node id’s in the csv?

This is the code I have:

```
nodes <- read.csv("Dataset1-Media-Example-NODES.csv", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE) #Assigns nodes in excel to variable nodes. Header = TRUE ensures that the top row is counted as a header.
edges <- read.csv("Dataset1-Media-Example-EDGES.csv", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE) #Assigns edges in excel to variable edges. Header = FALSE ensures that the top row is not counted as a header.
head(nodes) #preview
head(edges) #preview
edges


net3 <- network(edges, vertex.attr=nodes, matrix.type="edgelist", loops=TRUE, multiple=FALSE, ignore.eval=FALSE)
net3[,]

as.data.frame(net3)

plot(net3, displaylabels=TRUE)

es <- data.frame(onset=1:49,terminus=50,head=as.matrix(net3, matrix.type="edgelist")[,1],
                 tail=as.matrix(net3, matrix.type="edgelist")[,2])

es
```

Data can found following this link: https://www.researchgate.net/deref/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kateto.net%2Fwordpress%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F06%2Fsunbelt2019.zip

Unsure where this problem is coming from